# Transitioning to Tensorflow 1.0.0

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I am trying to translate [this](https://github.com/yenchenlin/pix2pix-tensorflow/blob/e0ef0323c5ccbd066fea117a012f5d7e748ee6ce/model.py) pix2pix GAN code to Tensorflow 1.0.0 using the following [script](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/compatibility/tf_upgrade.py) as described in Tensorflow Documentation, but I keep getting the following error:

> ValueError: Variable d_h0_conv/w/Adam/ does not exist, or was not
>   created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=None in
>   VarScope?

This is the Adam optimizer part:

```
 d_optim = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(args.lr, beta1=args.beta1) \
.minimize(self.d_loss, var_list=self.d_vars)
```

Where d_vars is:

```
t_vars = tf.trainable_variables()

self.d_vars = [var for var in t_vars if 'd_' in var.name]
```

And the discriminator code:

```
    def discriminator(self, image, y=None, reuse=False):
        # image is 256 x 256 x (input_c_dim + output_c_dim)
        if reuse:
            tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
        else:
            assert tf.get_variable_scope().reuse == False

        h0 = lrelu(conv2d(image, self.df_dim, name='d_h0_conv'))
        # h0 is (128 x 128 x self.df_dim)
        h1 = lrelu(self.d_bn1(conv2d(h0, self.df_dim*2, name='d_h1_conv')))
        # h1 is (64 x 64 x self.df_dim*2)
        h2 = lrelu(self.d_bn2(conv2d(h1, self.df_dim*4, name='d_h2_conv')))
        # h2 is (32x 32 x self.df_dim*4)
        h3 = lrelu(self.d_bn3(conv2d(h2, self.df_dim*8, d_h=1, d_w=1, name='d_h3_conv')))
        # h3 is (16 x 16 x self.df_dim*8)
        h4 = linear(tf.reshape(h3, [self.batch_size, -1]), 1, 'd_h3_lin')
  return tf.nn.sigmoid(h4), h4
```